# applying function to NA values in a column based on values in another column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, na

Here's an example of how my data looks like:

```
pupilsize <- c(500, 400, NA, NA, 100, 600, 500, NA, NA, NA, 500) 
rlelength <- c(4,4,2,2,6,6,6,90,90,90,50)
data <- data.frame(cbind(pupilsize,rlelength))
```

I would like to apply the na.approx function to the chunk of NA value in data$pupilsize **only** if the number in data$rlelength is smaller than 86.

The end result should be

```
data$pupilsize
[1] 500 400 300 200 100 600 500  NA  NA  NA 500
```

I am having a lot of trouble segmenting the chunk that of NA values I want. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
data$pupilsize <- with(data, ifelse(rlelength< 86, na.approx(pupilsize), pupilsize))
data$pupilsize
#[1] 500 400 300 200 100 600 500  NA  NA  NA 500
```

Or

```
i1 <- data$rlelength < 86
data$pupilsize[i1] <- na.approx(data$pupilsize[i1])
```

---

Or we can use `data.table` methods for efficiency.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[rlelength < 86, pupilsize := na.approx(pupilsize)]
```